# Arduino gsm shield requests

Tags: arduino, gsm

I am going to create a arduino gsm shield which acts as a central system. this gsm shield will recieve thousands of sms in a minute.

for an example many sms can come to the shield at the same time.
can arduino gsm shield bear the load of the reauests?

what hapen if two requests come to the shield same time?

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop at a pace which is suitable to the GSM module receiving the SMSs. Try hit and trial for this and see if it can cater multiple SMS simultaneously.

Also keep in mind that buffers are there to store your information unless it is full so my guess is that your data won't be lost.